# How to handle an event for user controls like JList in Java

Tags: c#, java, listbox, jlist, eventhandler

I'm a C# developer & i want to work with java too.
i dont know how to handle an event for User Controls like this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
listBox.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(listBox_2click);
...
void listBox_2click(object s , EventArgs e)
{
   // do sth.
}
```

Comment: There aren't really delegates in java, use the ActionListener, and related types for swing controls. A swing tutorial would help you out as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a MouseListener, and then check the getClickCount() method of the MouseEvent to check whether it was a double click.

Recommended reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html